# Java newbie need help finding further reading on 'new classname().withXxx(param)' and ClassName.class.method syntax

Tags: java, class, syntax, new-operator

Been searching Google/stackoverflow with various terms but they all are way too broad to pinpoint what I'm trying to find.

I am just looking at some AWS API code and want to read up on how to create my own code like this, which, I'm assuming is passing parameters using a chaining style:

```
ListDomainsRequest sdbRequest = new ListDomainsRequest().withMaxNumberOfDomains(100);
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

as well as the use of the class keyword herein:

```
AwsConsoleApp.class.getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties")
              ^^^^^
```

What are the proper names for these techniques? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is the [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). A quick wiki snip is...

> A fluent interface is normally implemented by using method chaining to relay the instruction context of a subsequent call

[Here is also a nice blog post](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) by Adewale Oshineye giving some general thoughts on the subject as well.

*[update] I just realized you question about class is separate from the first. For that you just need to realize that .class is a way to access the object's java.lang.Class type which is useful in certain cases.*

Comment: So is this basically the convention of returning the object itself for every call to methods on the object? I'm way more familiar with jQuery and chaining is The Way; was mainly wondering if it's "enabled" by 'return this' internally...thx!

Comment: Ah, and yes, doing a return this is will get you the desired affect.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is usually called a *class literal*, and it's just a feature of the Java language handled by the compiler. It ends up getting translated into a cached call to `Class.forName()`.

The first one is just *method chaining*; the idea is that any method that returns the object it was called on can be chained together infinitely this way. Some people like it, some people think it's an abomination. The abomination contingent has gotten smaller over time.